# quorum private transaction is giving error "Transaction has been reverted by the EVM"

Tags: quorum, quorum-maker

In my project, I have created a 3 node quorum network using quorum-maker. I am calling my smart contract method from web3js. Public transactions are working fine but private transactions are always reverted by EVM.

```
contract.methods.myMethod().send({ from: sendEtherAddress, gas: 3000000, privateFor: [publickey] })


Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x60530ed0a29d140eb5f2303169be9faf8152966612e47acb07ba91409e28e973",
  "blockNumber": 49,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 0,
  "from": "0x9c022e6495bea1a21defa776b9266efc88452195",
  "gasUsed": 0,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0xb9c94f33b7bebdee128c8aab172ec9157af02977",
  "transactionHash": "0x2f81869e1a43a585761997eec4447ce89b0bf9ba1c65b1db8376e26ce0bad304",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "events": {}
}
    at Object.TransactionError (/Users/vivart/training/blockchain/TradeApp/server/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:96:21)
    at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (/Users/vivart/training/blockchain/TradeApp/server/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:108:21)
    at /Users/vivart/training/blockchain/TradeApp/server/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:482:48
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) {
  receipt: {
    blockHash: '0x60530ed0a29d140eb5f2303169be9faf8152966612e47acb07ba91409e28e973',
    blockNumber: 49,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 0,
    from: '0x9c022e6495bea1a21defa776b9266efc88452195',
    gasUsed: 0,
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: false,
    to: '0xb9c94f33b7bebdee128c8aab172ec9157af02977',
    transactionHash: '0x2f81869e1a43a585761997eec4447ce89b0bf9ba1c65b1db8376e26ce0bad304',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    events: {}
  }
}
```

Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)
Solidity - 0.6.8 (solc-js)
Node v12.14.1
Web3.js v1.2.1
Quorum Maker V2.6.2
Quorum 2.2.1

genesis.json

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 18743,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "isQuorum": true
  },
  "alloc": {
    "0xc25909404771093ff94fdfd9b4d7de18549939dc": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty": "0x0",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0xE0000000",
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```

TradeInterface.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >0.5.2;

interface TradeInterface {
    
    event TradeCreated(bytes32 _tradeId, address _fromParty, address _toParty, uint _amount, uint _tradeDate);

    function addTrade(bytes32 _tradeId, address _fromParty, address _toParty, uint _amount, uint _tradeDate) external;

    function getTrade(bytes32 _tradeId) external view returns (address, address, uint, uint);
}
```

TradeImpl.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity >0.5.2;

import "./TradeInterface.sol";

contract TradeImpl is TradeInterface {    
    struct tradeStruct {
        bytes32 tradeId;
        address fromParty;
        address toParty;
        uint amount;
        uint tradeDate;
    }
    mapping (bytes32 => tradeStruct) tradeList;
    
    function  addTrade(bytes32 _tradeId, address _fromParty, address _toParty, uint _amount, uint _tradeDate) override external {
        tradeList[_tradeId] = tradeStruct(_tradeId,_fromParty,_toParty,_amount,_tradeDate);
        emit TradeCreated(_tradeId,_fromParty,_toParty,_amount,_tradeDate);            
    }
    
    function getTrade(bytes32 _tradeId) public override view returns (address, address, uint, uint) {
        return (tradeList[_tradeId].toParty, tradeList[_tradeId].fromParty, tradeList[_tradeId].amount,tradeList[_tradeId].tradeDate);
    }
}
```

Web3SEervice.js

```
const addTrade = async (trade) => {
    const httpProvider = getHttpProvider(trade.fromParty);
    const web3 = new Web3(httpProvider);
    const id = await web3.eth.net.getId();
    const deployedNetwork = tradeInterface.networks[id];
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    const sendEtherAddress = accounts[0];
    const tradeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(tradeInterface.abi, deployedNetwork.address);
    const tradeId = web3js.utils.asciiToHex(trade.tradeId);
    const fromParty = getNodeAdress(trade.fromParty);
    const toParty = getNodeAdress(trade.toParty);
    const date = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
    const amount = trade.amount;

    let sendParams = { from: sendEtherAddress, gas: 30000000 };
    if (trade.isPrivate) {
        sendParams = { from: sendEtherAddress, gas: 30000000, privateFor: [getNodePublicKey(trade.toParty)] };
    }
    return tradeContract.methods.addTrade(
        tradeId,
        fromParty,
        toParty,
        amount,
        date
    ).send(sendParams);
}
```

truffle-config.js

```
development: {
     host: "host-ip",     
     port: 22000,            
     network_id: "*",
     gas: 0,
     gasPrice: 0,
     type: "quorum",     
    }
```

Node logs

```
sending private tx                       privatefrom= privatefor="[QfeDAys9MPDs2XHExtc84jKGHxZg/aj52DTh0vtA3Xc=]"
DEBUG[08-26|20:36:49.204] sent private tx                          privatefrom= privatefor="[QfeDAys9MPDs2XHExtc84jKGHxZg/aj52DTh0vtA3Xc=]"
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.204] Private transaction signing with QuorumPrivateTxSigner 
TRACE[08-26|20:36:49.206] Pooled new future transaction            hash=67ac4f…5cd1cf from=0xed9d02e382b34818e88B88a309c7fe71E65f419d to=0x9d13C6D3aFE1721BEef56B55D303B09E021E27ab
TRACE[08-26|20:36:49.206] Promoting queued transaction             hash=67ac4f…5cd1cf
TRACE[08-26|20:36:49.206] Promoting queued transaction             hash=67ac4f…5cd1cf
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.206] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x67ac4f260b95cfd25640a008129e0784a14905a561efcbf38039b968215cd1cf recipient=0x9d13C6D3aFE1721BEef56B55D303B
09E021E27ab
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.206] QUORUM-CHECKPOINT                        name=TX-CREATED              tx=0x67ac4f260b95cfd25640a008129e0784a14905a561efcbf38039b968215cd1cf to=0x9d13C6D3aFE17
21BEef56B55D303B09E021E27ab
DEBUG[08-26|20:36:49.206] Served eth_sendTransaction               conn=92.23.215.88:51084 reqid=5             t=242.809845ms
TRACE[08-26|20:36:49.206] Broadcast transaction                    hash=67ac4f…5cd1cf recipients=2
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.207] VM returned with error                   err="VM in read-only mode. Mutating opcode prohibited"
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.207] QUORUM-CHECKPOINT                        name=TX-COMPLETED            tx=0x67ac4f260b95cfd25640a008129e0784a14905a561efcbf38039b968215cd1cf time=356.044µs
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.207] Generated next block                     block num=6 num txes=1
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.207]   Mined block                           number=6 hash=fb6478e7      elapsed=904.157µs
TRACE[08-26|20:36:49.208] Broadcast transactions                   id=995dbe18829f1aff conn=inbound            count=1
TRACE[08-26|20:36:49.209] Broadcast transactions                   id=c39143f98d04e97b conn=inbound            count=1
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.211] QUORUM-CHECKPOINT                        name=TX-ACCEPTED             tx=0x67ac4f260b95cfd25640a008129e0784a14905a561efcbf38039b968215cd1cf
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.211] VM returned with error                   err="VM in read-only mode. Mutating opcode prohibited"
DEBUG[08-26|20:36:49.211] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B     time=5.073µs   gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
DEBUG[08-26|20:36:49.212] Inserted new block                       number=6 hash=fb6478…8b9fd7 uncles=0 txs=1 gas=0      elapsed=1.073ms    root=b99f0b…c6bc74
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.212] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=1 mgas=0.000 elapsed=1.206ms    mgasps=0.000   number=6 hash=fb6478…8b9fd7 dirty=11.60KiB
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.212] QUORUM-CHECKPOINT                        name=BLOCK-CREATED           block=fb6478e7fe918af400c5967d9e44e4e5324c9065f4dfbed52c407ecaed8b9fd7
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.212] persisted the latest applied index       index=10
DEBUG[08-26|20:36:49.212] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
TRACE[08-26|20:36:49.212] Removed old pending transaction          hash=67ac4f…5cd1cf
INFO [08-26|20:36:49.212] Not minting a new block since there are no pending transactions
```

Comment: Can you share your genesis file, Quorum version, and solc version used?

Comment: I have updated all the information.

Answer (score 1):

so the problem is that your solidity compiler outstrips the abilities of the Quorum version you are using. This means that you compile newer solidity code that Quorum v2.2.1 cannot run correctly.

You have a few choices here:

- Downgrade solidity code and compiler to 0.4 / 0.5
- Upgrade Quorum client. Latest version of Quorum is v2.7.0 and it would work just fine
- To make the testing of this simple, please replace Quorum Maker (a 3rd party tool we do not support) with a more modern replacement that would set up the net for you: Quorum Wizard. Instruction here: https://github.com/ConsenSys/quorum-wizard

Comment: I have created 3 node network using quorum wizard and still I am getting same error "Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:"

Comment: I have added my smart contract code and web3js code too.

Comment: My apologies, 2 notes: did you also update genesis? You need istanbulBlock: 0 in it. And Could you also attach node logs?

Comment: I have not updated but I can see quorum-wizard/network/3-nodes-quickstart/resources/genesis.json has "istanbulBlock": 0 inside config.

Comment: Added Node logs too.

Comment: There are several reasons this error may be generated. One of the main is that when sending / making a new contract it must be private. It is then always private between the nodes and you cannot send public txns with it.

Comment: Another reason this error may appear is that you are trying to modify a public contract from a private one. Private contracts can only read data from public contracts.

Comment: Thanks, It's working now. After deploying contract privately 
`deployer.deploy(TradeImpl, {privateFor: ["privateKey1", "privateKey2", "privateKey2"]});`